# Firebase logs are not working, and Can not see logs on firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics

I'm trying to send logs to firebase within non-fatal issue but it does not work, and I can not see the logs in the firebase.
Thanks

```
var numberOfPhotoDownload = 0
        var didAllPhotosDownloadSuccessfully = true
        if (photosToDownloadChunks.size > 0) {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(Exception("API : Get Photos"))
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("API : Get Photos")
            for (chunck in photosToDownloadChunks){
                for (photo in chunck){
                    numberOfPhotoDownload++
                }
            }
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("Number of photos to download: $numberOfPhotoDownload")
            var count = 1
            for (chunck in photosToDownloadChunks){
                for (photo in chunck){
                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("Photo number #${count} " + "Photo_filename: ${photo.fileName}")
                    count++
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]